# Python - Transposing data blocks to columns

Tags: python, transpose

I have an unfortunate data structure in a file:

```
Time Value
1    x
2    y
3    z
....
Time Value
4    a
5    b
6    c
...
```

There are 2 columns and each is repeated vertically in the file.... I would like to transpose the blocks such as:

```
Time Value  Time   Value
1    x      1       a
2    y      2       b
3    z      3       c
...         ...
```

Each data set is not a fixed length either (only 3 rows are shown).

The data can be put out into a new file.

Comment: Does this involve any transposition? It looks like it's just concatenating (horizontally) 2 matrices, or even simpler: string formatting.

Comment: I would guess not.  The rows just need to be separated by the "Time/Value" separators and put into columns.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far. Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages for further details.